# cache populates wrong checkboxs in jQuery datatable MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, browser-cache

My mvc view has a table using .datatable . Each row has many columns, name ... and a checkbox. if I sort the table by another column than the original name then navigate away then press back, the cache loads the viewmodel data into the table using the name sort, but then the cache seems to be checking the check boxes based on the previously checked rows that were using a different sort.

ex.

(original)

```
name | number |checked
A    |   3    |
B    |   1    |   X
C    |   2    |
```

order by number ( .datatable)

```
name | number |checked
B    |   1    |   X
C    |   2    |
A    |   3    |
```

go to a new page then come back

i put a wait on javascript afer .ready so I could see the un-styled table

```
name | number |checked
A    |   3    |   X
B    |   1    |   
C    |   2    |
```

then once the datatable runs

```
name | number |checked
B    |   1    |   
C    |   2    |
A    |   3    |  X
```

I tested this in chrome, and IE and the problem occurs only in chrome.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="text-  transform:none!important">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name
                </th>
                <th>Number
                </th>
                <th>Checked
                </th>
</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (@Model.records.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in @Model.records)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.number</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBox("chkhide", @item.IsHidden, new { @class = "hide_check", id = item.Id })</td>

 </tr>
                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('.table').dataTable(
      {
          "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
          "oTableTools": {
              "sSwfPath": "../../../../Content/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
              "aButtons": ["copy", "csv"]
          },
          "bPaginate": false,
          "bSortCellsTop": true,
          "bSortClasses": false,
          "bStateSave": true
      });
```

Comment: Need some code or a js fiddle, otherwise im just flapping in the breeze as to why

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by forcing server side refresh of model data. IT looks like it is just a bug with datatables interface with chrome's cacheing system.